# Monomials forming basis of global sections of (powers of) some ample line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What are interesting examples of monomials forming a basis (as a vector space) for global sections of (powers of) some ample line bundle of a smooth projective variety?

I've seen examples of such collections of monomials from ample line bundles on certain toric varieties (without smooth projective assumption), but I'm not sure where else to look for these kinds of examples other than monomials of a fixed degree from $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)$.

Comment: Are you interested in "almost" answers? I'm woefully underinformed on toric varieties, but I think the moment you step out of monomial land you are guaranteed (almost guaranteed?) to leave toric land. But anyway, there is a presentation of the moduli space $\overline M_{0,n}$ of stable genus $0$ curves with $n$ marked points due to Hassett (based on an earlier version of Kapranov) which involves taking $\mathbb P^{n-3}$ and blowing up coordinate points, then coordinate lines, then coordinate planes etc. So global sections of line bundles on the moduli space end up corresponding to monomials...

Comment: ...that vanish to certain orders along the coordinate hyperplanes. But I lied; you actually have to blow up $n-1$ points (and include all of the possible spans in the higher-dimensional blowup centers), so besides the coordinate points you have to pick ONE more point (usually taken to be $[1:1:\cdots:1]$). Thus the monomial description doesn't QUITE work, and in fact the variety fails to be toric because of this extra point.